# unittesting perform click on a specific view in a childview in exandablelist view

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso

I have an expandablelistview (for now I can't upgrade it for recycleview) My requirement is to create a test which will open an item in the expandable listview, then click on a specific view inside the child view.

I managed to write the unit testing just to open the expandable view but I was not able to pick one of the children and press on a specific view.

This is my code so far:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestingListItemClick {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ClockActivity> rule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(ClockActivity.class, false, false);

    private Activity launchedActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        launchedActivity = rule.launchActivity(intent);

        // Context of the app under test.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        onView(withId(R.id.root_view)).perform(click());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Test
    public void itemClick() {


        DataInteraction dataInteraction = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lvTodoList)).atPosition(3);
        dataInteraction.perform(click());


//        dataInteraction.onChildView(withId(R.id.todolisttop)).atPosition(0).perform(click());
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(5000);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        dataInteraction.atPosition(0).perform(click());


//        onView(withId(R.id.lvTodoList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(3, click()));
//        onView(withId(R.id.lvTodoList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,
//                                ChildViewAction.clickChildViewWithId(
//                                        R.id.smart_action)));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

I added several thread sleep because I'm waiting for server responses during the workflow.

thank you